# How to get INDEX of the List from a Model Class Flutter out from Listview.builder

Tags: flutter

I have a class

```
class Consultant {
  final int id;
  final String consultantFirstName;
  final String consultantLastName;
  final String consultantNickName;

  const Consultant({
    this.id,
    this.consultantFirstName,
    this.consultantLastName,
    this.consultantNickName,

  });
}

final Consultant marco = Consultant(
    id: 1,
    consultantFirstName: 'Marco',
    consultantLastName: 'Marcello',
    
);
final Consultant carmela = Consultant(
    id: 2,
    consultantFirstName: 'Carmela',
    consultantLastName: 'Maiocchi',
    consultantNickName: 'Mariz Safe',


List<Consultant> consultant = [
  marco,
  carmela,

];
```

If I call this list into ListviewBuilder all is fine because of INDEX into a Listviewbuilder,
the problem is if I am out of ListViewbuilder I cant get the index and I get error because there is not Index if I call `consultant: consultant[index];` to pass data to a new widget
here is how I call into Listview.builder and I get value:

```
ListView.builder(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                itemCount: consultant.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () => Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (_) => ConsultantProfile(
                              consultant: consultant[index],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
```

but if I go out from Listview.builder widget and I try to call another widget passing the data as this:

```
appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(
            'Desteeno',
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w300, color: Colors.white),
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
          centerTitle: true,
          elevation: 15,
          shadowColor: Colors.black,
          actions: [
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
                showDialog(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (context) => ContactForm(
                    consultant: consultant[index],
                  ),
                );
              },
```

I get index red underlined and error:
  `The getter 'index' isn't defined for the class '_ConsultantProfileState'`
I understand I need to define the index from my List but I dont know how

Comment: add some more code like how you will be using it...

Comment: I edited the code and add some more.

Comment: from where are you getting the index of consultant in this code  the appear one??

Comment: the index is from the Class Consultant

Comment: I mean how are you getting which index ex 1,2,3 or 4 , is there anyway by which you are getting item from consultant you want use

Comment: yes by clicking on a list of the consultant
I generate a List of consultant from such class and then once this list is created I click on the right Consultant user

Comment: You can access the object that you passed to the widget with `widget.consultant`. In the second code change `consultant[index]` to `widget.consultant`

Comment: so the 2nd code you have written is of  ConsultantProfile() ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this , it should help:

```
appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(
            'Desteeno',
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w300, color: Colors.white),
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
          centerTitle: true,
          elevation: 15,
          shadowColor: Colors.black,
          actions: [
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
                showDialog(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (context) => ContactForm(
                    consultant: widget.consultant,
                  ),
                );
```